# File system errors. Is my hard disk failing? Or this error is because of me?

Tags: linux, filesystems, boot, fsck, smartctl

My machine is Dell 7559 i5 with a GTX960m graphics card.

I have a problem when I install GNU/Linux (any distribution) on my machine, after some days it crashes and has file system errors.

I corrected the initial errors using `fsck` but now it takes a really long time to correct. Just today I spent 7- 9 hours running `fsck` for a single partition in my drive. Also on previous tries after I had fixed the file systems using `fsck`, it crashed when ever I tried to boot in my non-root account. I could only login as root. I don't think the issue is with Nvidia drivers as I run my Linux Nvidia-Off (`noveau.modeset=0`).

The issue has a pattern though i. e. whenever I'll download, copy, create files in my system, it crashes after a few logins after that. I could login as root and have been logging as root for a past couple of days with zero problems.

But yesterday when I worked on a LibreOffice document and rebooted the machine, it crashed again. This made me think that this might be a hard disk issue. So I went into recovery mode and pulled SMART data as someone suggested. It says it found over 7000 errors. And `smartctl - l selftest /dev/sda` gave the following info:

Why is this happening? I am new to Linux and have been trying to use it for about a month now. This is my main issue.

[image]

Comment: You should post the crash details (from /var/log/messages or /var/log/messages or /var/log/kern.log or by doing `journalctl -b -1 ` if you are on a systemd-based system - wherever your system stores that information). If your machine is capable of booting from USB (most are nowadays), you can try installing on an external USB disk (you can get a 1TB one for about $50 I would guess) and boot off that. If that works, I would suggest you replace your hard drive. There may be other diagnostic steps you can take: `dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M` will read the whole disk: if it gets errors, replace the disk.

Comment: Dell might have a diagnostic utility as well: call them and ask.

Comment: Dell Support pointed out that i have a faulty hard drive. I was just hoping for any other solutions than change my hard drive. I guess I will change out my hard drive. Thanks NickD.